# ORACLE-SQL: Function, how to detect a null selection and return 0

Tags: sql, oracle, function, count

I have wrote the following function. But at the end I'm not able when count is empty to detect it and put in the `result` variable returning 0;  I don't know what is wrong, maybe count(*) should be put by an external SELECT, no sure.

Running for example, random input:

```
SELECT is_department_active('44','222') from dual
```

I got `is_department_active` (null) but expected 0.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_department_active (
        department_id   VARCHAR2,
        doc_id      VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN NUMBER IS
        result NUMBER(1);  
        cnt number(3);
    BEGIN
    result:=0;
        SELECT
            dep_active, count(*)
        INTO result,cnt
        FROM
            (
           SELECT
            grade,
            dep_active,  3 "priority number"
        FROM
            vrsc.inst_department
        WHERE
            af_feature_id = department_id
            AND grade = 'DOC'
            AND grade_field = doc_id
        UNION
        SELECT grade,
            dep_active,
            1 "priority number"
        FROM
            vrsc.inst_department
        WHERE
            af_feature_id = department_id
            AND grade = 'CUSTOMER'
            AND grade_field IN (
                SELECT
                    doc_cust_id
                FROM
                    customer_docs
                WHERE
                    doc_id = doc_id)
        UNION
        SELECT
            grade,
            dep_active,
            0 "priority number"
        FROM
            vrsc.inst_department
        WHERE
            af_feature_id = department_id
            AND grade = 'DEFAULT'
            AND GRADE_FIELD = 'DEFAULT'
        UNION
        SELECT
            grade, dep_active,
            2 "priority number"
        FROM
            vrsc.groups_docs left
            JOIN vrsc.inst_department ON grade = 'GROUP'
                                      AND grade_field = gs_group_id
                                      AND grade_sec_field = gs_doc_code
        WHERE
            gs_doc_id = doc_id
            AND af_feature_id = feature_id
        ORDER BY
            "priority number" DESC
            )
        WHERE
            ROWNUM = 1 group by dep_active;
            if cnt=0 then
            result:=0;
            end if;
    
        RETURN result;
    END;
```

I would like to take the first row wit priority 3, but if this query is null, empty then I can't return 0 as DEFAULT.

[image]

Comment: If you run the "SELECT AND UNION INSIDE" subquery with those arguments, what does the result look like? If it's returning `null, 1` that would cause this problem.

Comment: Code you wrote looks kind of *bad* (don't take me wrong, but ... aggregation with ROWNUM = 1 really looks suspicious). Maybe it would be better if you posted some sample data and explained what it means that some department is considered to be "active". Perhaps someone would suggest better approach than yours.

Comment: @kfinity I put the part inside select and union, it gives me empty

Comment: @Littlefoot I edited and put the part inside: select and union

Comment: I posted an answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

From my original function I substitute IF statement with EXCEPTION and removed the counter

```
--previous code  without IF   
RETURN result;
    
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
        RETURN 0;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

After you edited the question and included the whole code, there's nothing much I can say about it; I trust you that query you wrote actually decides whether department is active or not.

I'd suggest such a code - simplified - to decide the final result:

```
with temp as
  (select bunch of things you currently select)
select nvl(max(1), 0)
  into result
  from dual
  where exists (select null from temp);
```

No `IF`s, `ROWNUM`s, `COUNT`s ... as simple as that (while "bunch of things" *is* complex, though).

Or, put into the function:

```
create or replace function 
  is_department_active (department_id in varchar2, doc_id in varchar2)
  return number 
is
  result number(1);
begin
  with temp as(select grade,
                    dep_active,
                    3 "priority number"
             from vrsc.inst_department
             where af_feature_id = department_id
                   and grade = 'doc'
                   and grade_field = doc_id
             union
             select grade,
                    dep_active,
                    1 "priority number"
             from vrsc.inst_department
             where af_feature_id = department_id
                   and grade = 'CUSTOMER'
                   and grade_field in(select doc_cust_id
                                from customer_docs
                                where doc_id = doc_id
                                     )
             union
             select grade,
                    dep_active,
                    0 "priority number"
             from vrsc.inst_department
             where af_feature_id = department_id
                   and grade = 'DEFAULT'
                   and grade_field = 'DEFAULT'
             union
             select grade,
                    dep_active,
                    2 "priority number"
             from vrsc.groups_docs left
             join vrsc.inst_department on grade = 'GROUP'
                                          and grade_field = gs_group_id
                                          and grade_sec_field = gs_doc_code
             where gs_doc_id = doc_id
                   and af_feature_id = feature_id
             order by "priority number" desc)
  select nvl(max(1), 0)
  into result
  from temp
  where exists (select null from temp);

  return result;
end;
```

See if it helps.

Comment: if you look the picture, I need the first row. It could be active = 1 or not active = 0, don't mind what is. But by my query when it is for example null, it should assume value =0, DEFAULT.

Comment: @Littlefoot: maybe OutofMemoryError asked sth different. He doesn’t need the count, but to order by priority and to take what is the result active or not active. As you can check on his code. That is correct, needs only to detect null result and to exchange with 0. Only that.

Answer (score 0):

See the [NVL](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-comparison-functions/oracle-nvl/) function, and try this:

```
  if nvl(cnt,0) = 0 then
    result:=0;
  end if;
```

Comment: I tried it before but give me back null not 0. I think the clue is on rownum, maybe to speculate the result of it.

Comment: there is no way NVL can return null like that.

Comment: I got this. I don't know why.